# convert a textview, including those contents off the screen, to bitmap

Tags: android, view, bitmap, textview

I want to save(export) contents of MyView, which extends TextView, into a bitmap.

I followed the code: [this][1].

It works fine when the size of the text is small.

But when there are lots of texts, and some of the content is out of the screen, what I got is only what showed in the screen.

Then I add a "layout" in my code:

```
private class MyView extends TextView{
    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Bitmap export(){
        Layout l = getLayout();
        int width = l.getWidth() + getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
        int height = l.getHeight() + getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();

        Bitmap viewBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(viewBitmap);


        setCursorVisible(false);
        layout(0, 0, width, height);
        draw(canvas);

        setCursorVisible(true);
        return viewBitmap;
    }
}
```

Now the strange thing happened:

The first time I invoke "export"(I use an option key to do that), I got contents only on the screen.

When I invoke "export" again, I got complete contents, including those out of the screen.

Why?

How to "export" a view, including contents cannot be showed on the screen?

Thank you!

[1]: http://www.techjini.com/blog/2010/02/10/quicktip-how-to-convert-a-view-to-an-image-android/ this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out a simpler way:
Put the TextView in a ScrollView.
Now myTextView.draw(canvas) will draw all of the text.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be subtracting the padding from the width in the height instead of adding it. Adding it will give you an area larger than the screen.

Comment: I tried subtracting, but that make the "export" bitmap smaller than what it appears in the screen, and some contents were truncated.

Comment: @user623318 - Perhaps you shouldn't be adding or subtracting the padding then. Before you were getting larger contents then when subtracting you got smaller so without the padding you should get the entire screen size correct?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue this way(strange but works):

```
public Bitmap export(){
    //...
    LayoutParams lp = getLayoutParams();
    int old_width = lp.width;
    int old_height = lp.height;
    int old_scroll_x = getScrollX();
    int old_scroll_y = getScrollY();
    lp.width = width;
    lp.height = height;
    layout(0, 0, width, height);
    scrollTo(0, 0);
    draw(canvas);
    lp.width = old_width;
    lp.height = old_height;
    setLayoutParams(lp);
    scrollTo(old_scroll_x, old_scroll_y);
    //...
```

}